# Java-Scanner not working with nextByte()

Tags: java

```
Scanner Sc = new Scanner(new File("Input.bin"));
String s = Sc.nextLine();
fsize = Integer.parseInt(s); // Reads 4

s = Sc.nextLine();
int mapSize = Integer.parseInt(s);     // Reads 3 
for (int i = 0; i < mapSize; i++)
{
    byte value = 0;
    value = Sc.nextByte();  // Here it is throwing the exception it should have
                            // print the ascii of 'b' which is 98????

    String key = Sc.nextLine();
    key = key.trim();

    dcMap.put(key, (char)value);
 // System.out.println(key + " " + (char)value);
}
```

*Input.bin* file contents:

```
4
3
b 0
c 10
a 11
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the exception?

Comment: It is probably throwing a `InputMismatchException`, is it?

Answer (score 5):

`java.util.Scanner` is intended for scanning *text*.

So when you call `Scanner#nextByte()`, what it really expects to find is a textual representation of a number. For example, if you had "98" there instead of "b", it would have read 98 into that byte variable.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` is used for parsing **text**, the [`Scanner#nextByte()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextByte%28%29) method try to match an input composed of digits (signed or not) to convert it in the equivalent single byte value.

**It's not the reverse, it will not read a letter and return his byte value.**

If you want to know what Scanner try to match, take a look at the method `hasNextByte()` (checked whether or not a byte can be read). It try to match this pattern :

> "(([-+]?(((((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})++)|(\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]?((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})?(\ ((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))))|(((((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})++)|(\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]?((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})?(\ ((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))|(\Q-\E((((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})++)|(\p{javaDigit}&&[^0]?((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})?(\ ((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit})((?i)[0123456789]|\p{javaDigit}))+)))"

So you see there that it only looks for digits.

Answer (score -1):

The JavaDoc for nextByte says:

> If the next token matches the Integer regular expression defined above
>   then the token is converted into a byte value

So it's expecting an integer token as a string which is then converted into a byte. Try using the next() method instead to obtain the token as a string. You can then convert the character into a byte yourself.